# Activity Indicator is not showed when loading large amount of data from sqlite database

Tags: ios, sqlite, uiactivityindicatorview

In my app, i'm getting the data from database. The data that I get from database is very large like 20000 records. So, I want to show an activity indicator to indicate that data is loading. But activity indicator is not showed when I run the app.

I'm sending code for this. Please help me out.

```
activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];

activityIndicator.frame = CGRectMake(100,100, 20, 20);
[self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];

[activityIndicator startAnimating];

// Code to get data from database

[activityIndicator stopAnimating];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you don't need to set the frame for the activiyIndicator.  You can just set the centre...

```
activityIndicator.center = self.view.center; (or soemthing like this).
```

Second, how are you retrieving the data?  Are you doing it all on the main thread?  Or are you doing it asynchronously?

::EDIT::

Ah it appears you are doing this...

```
[actInd startAnimating];
[self getData];  //this is asynchronous
[actInd stopAnimating];
```

if this is the case then the stopAnimating will get called almost immediately.

What you need is something like this...

```
[actInd startAnimating];
[self getData];  //this is asynchronous
```

Then in getData...

```
- (void)getData
{
    //get all your data and process it....

    [actInd stopAnimating];
}
```

This way the stop animating will only get called after doing all the data work.

If that doesn't work try removing the stopAnimating altogether to check it is actually animating in the first place.

Comment: I'm doing it asynchronously '[activityIndicator startAnimating];         array = [SQLite getDataFromDB]; [activityIndicator stopAnimating];'

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
activityIndicator = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
activityIndicator.center = self.view.center; 
[self.view addSubview:activityIndicator];
[NSThread detachNewThreadSelector:@selector(startActivityIndicator) toTarget:self withObject:nil];
```

Add this method:

```
-(void)startActivityIndicator
{
  NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
  [activityIndicator startAnimating];
  [pool release];
}
```

Do changes:

```
- (void)getData
{
  //get all your data from database.
  [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

@Fogmeister is wright about setting the frame of activityIndicator.

and for showing the activityIndicator just create one function of the code shown in your question and call it using the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` with delay of 0.001 and the activityIndicator will shown

Happy Coding :)